# como paso un json a un array en Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

tengo una pequeña duda, la cual consiste en que tengo que poner un  `json` a un  `array`,

Mi jquery:

```
function girar_ruleta() {
var mesa = $("#numero_unico").val();
$('#ruleta_giratoria').modal('show');
$.post("php/traer_madres.php", {mesa: mesa}, function (data) {
    var dato = $.trim(data);
    console.log(dato);
});
```

}

lo que me devuelve `data`

```
{"data":[{"nombre_completo":"YOLANDA MEJIA ROJAS"},{"nombre_completo":"IRMA VARA SANCHEZ"},{"nombre_completo":"DIANA AGUAYO MORENO"}]}
```

Eso lo quiero pasar a un array.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿`var arr = Object.values(data);` ?

Comment: Me devuelve cada carecter en un array `Array [ "{", """, "d", "a", "t", "a", """, ":", "[", "{", 124 más… ]`

Comment: No sé como lo estás haciendo pero a mí me funciona perfectamente con el JSON que muestras.

Comment: Has intentado usar la función de jQuery `$.parseJSON` ?

Comment: cuando pongo alert en vez de console mi resulta es `"{\"data\":[{\"nombre_completo\":\"YOLANDA MEJIA ROJAS\"},{\"nombre_completo\":\"IRMA VARA SANCHEZ\"},{\"nombre_completo\":\"DIANA AGUAYO MORENO\"}]}"`

Comment: Para estar seguro de que regresas un JSON verifica en php/traer_madres.php que tengas algo como esto echo json_encode($respuesta); una vez que regresa a tu front para poder acceder a tu respuesta, en este caso data, sólo debes hacer data["data"] y con eso obtienes los valores. Esto también depende de cómo estés armando tu json en php, también considero que var dato = $.trim(data); esté afectado la estructura del objeto

Comment: data tiene un array. No entiendo tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itera entre los datos con un `for` y agrégalos a tu arra con un `push`.

en tu  caso quedaria asi:

```
function girar_ruleta() {
    var mesa = $("#numero_unico").val();
    $('#ruleta_giratoria').modal('show');
    $.post("php/traer_madres.php", {mesa: mesa}, function (data) {
        //si tu data es un string agrega
        data=$.parseJSON(data);

        dato=[];
        for (element in data.data) { 
            dato.push(data.data[element]["nombre_completo"])
        };
        console.log(dato);
    });
 }
```

```js
    data={"data":[{"nombre_completo":"YOLANDA MEJIA ROJAS"}, {"nombre_completo":"IRMA VARA SANCHEZ"},{"nombre_completo":"DIANA AGUAYO MORENO"}]}
dato=[];
for (element in data.data) { 
     dato.push(data.data[element]["nombre_completo"])
};
console.log(dato);
```

Comment: `{"data":[{"nombre_completo":"YOLANDA MEJIA ROJAS"},{"nombre_completo":"IRMA VARA SANCHEZ"},{"nombre_completo":"DIANA AGUAYO MORENO"}]}`

Comment: El element que varieble es? xq lo copio igual y me bota vacion  `Arra[  ]`

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores element es el iterador del for

Comment: nada me sale Array[   ]

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores si intentaste usar `data=$.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: Gracias espero que califiques mas 1 para no perder mi reputacion gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para estar seguro de que regresas un JSON verifica en php/traer_madres.php que tengas algo como esto echo json_encode($respuesta); una vez que regresa a tu front para poder acceder a tu respuesta, en este caso data, sólo debes hacer data["data"] y con eso obtienes los valores. Esto también depende de cómo estés armando tu json en php, también considero que var dato = $.trim(data); esté afectado la estructura del objeto.

Ejemplo respuesta php

```
$datos[1]["nombre_completo"] = "YOLANDA MEJIA ROJAS";
$datos[2]["nombre_completo"] = "IRMA VARA SANCHEZ";
$respuesta = array("data"=>$datos);

echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

En tu js recibirías de esta manera.

```
function girar_ruleta() {
var mesa = $("#numero_unico").val();
$('#ruleta_giratoria').modal('show');
$.post("php/traer_madres.php", {mesa: mesa}, function (data) {
    $.each(data["data"], function(i, persona) {
            alert(persona.nombre_completo);
    });
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo pasa el response de tu servicio a arrays de esta forma:

```
var arr = Object.values(response)
```